# transformation of variables in a fokker planck PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following Fokker Planck PDE:
$$
\dfrac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial t}
=
-\dfrac{\partial u(t,x)}{\partial x}
+
\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}[ 3 x^2 u(t,x)].
$$

Can't figure out a way (transformation of $x$) to reduce it to the basic $u_t=0.5 u_{xx}$ or anything with a known solution for that matter. Would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.